# No Method Error on edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to edit my events model. Here is what I have for the edit:

## Edit Event

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.label :description %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
        <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I made the route as so:

```
  resources :events do
    member do
      post :attend
      post "/remove_attendee/:user_id" => "events#remove_attendee", :as=>:remove_attendee
      post "/edit" => "events#edit"
    end
```

But I am getting a no method error. NoMethodError in Events#edit and it is on line 3 which is the form_for place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your controller code look like? Also, could you paste the exact NoMethodError that is thrown? (It contains useful info, like which method did Ruby try to call on an object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in your view, the `form_for` tag calls some methods on the resource passed in, in this case `@event`.  Make sure that `@event` is not nil and that the lookup to pull up the resource is working as intended. Again, seeing you controller/model/etc. code along with the full error would help.

Comment: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Edit Event</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
4:  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
5:  <div class="actions">
6:   <%= f.label :name %><br />

Comment: And your controller code that should be making @event available is...?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are setting @event in your controller.